# returning count of elements occuring in a list in R without grep

Tags: r, list

I need to search a set of values(dynamic) in a list without using `grep`.

After calculation I get an set of values stored in a vector,e.g.:

```
vec<-c("146002","1976867")
```

list_a:

```
[[1]]
[1] "318484"  "146002"  "1453825" "1976867" "1591246"

[[2]]
[1] "1059410" "1370072" "787848"  "2075616" "456048"  "669019"  "2151636" "557068"  "32948"   "595490"  "1752826"
```

I need to return the no of times the elements of `vec` appear in the `list_a`.

Comment: I am just curious: Why no `grep`?

Comment: If I have a value of 826 in vec but in list_a have values such as 102826,etc then grep would produce problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `lapply` with `%in%` seems to do it.

```
> lapply(seq(length(list_a)), function(i) sum(list_a[[i]] %in% vec))
## [[1]]
## [1] 2

## [[2]]
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `table`:

```
vec <- c("146002", "1976867")

a_list <- list(c("318484", "146002", "1453825",  "1976867",  "1591246"),
               c("1059410", "1370072",  "787848", "2075616", "456048",
                 "669019", "2151636", "557068", "32948", "595490", "1752826"))

table(unlist(a_list))[vec]
# 146002 1976867 
#      1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match whole string using `^` and `$`.

```
grep("^123$",c("123","1234","4123","123123","123"))
```